# How to use list parameter as table in JPQL

Tags: java, spring, database, jpa, jpql

I have a table like this.

```sql
create table gains (
  user_id varchar,
  recorded_at datetime,
  amount integer
)
```

I want to do an aggregate query against it with a given list of datetime, which would return something like this. (Pseudo-code follows)

Arguments:

```java
String userId = "1";
List<Instant> aggregateAts = Arrays.asList(Instant.parse("2023-12-01T00:00Z"),Instant.parse("2023-12-02T00:00Z"),Instant.parse("2023-12-03T00:00Z"));
List<GainsHistory> result = gainsHistoryRepository.generate(userId, aggregateAts);
...
public interface GainsHistory implements Repository<GainsHistory,GainsHistoryPK> {
  @Query("...")
  List<GainsHistory> generate(String userId, List<Instant> aggregateAts);
}
```

Wanted result:

| user_id | aggregate_at | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-12-01T00:00Z | 100.00 |
| 1 | 2023-12-02T00:00Z | 110.00 |
| 1 | 2023-12-03T00:00Z | 120.00 |

I can already do this with a single `aggregateAt` value with JPQL (i.e. `select g.userId, :aggregateAt, sum(g.amount) from Gains g where g.userId = :userId, g.recordedAt < :aggregateAt`), or even the method naming convention magic, but I want to be able to pass a list of dates and return rows each with amounts aggregated at the dates from `aggregateAts` passed as method arguments.

My question is

1. Is this possible with just JPQL (no native query)
2. If yes, how do we do it?

JPQL don't have CTE as far as I know, so that I generate rows and join the select to that table. I know using native query with CTE or temp table is possible (have one working), but I want to know if this is possible with just JPQL.

I was finding ways to convert the list of parameters into rows that I can left join to in JPQL, but have not found a solution.

Comment: What about `IN` or `NOT IN` clauses have you tried these yet ?

Comment: `IN` clause gets the list argument as value tuples `(?, ?, ?, ... ?)`  which cannot be transposed into rows of a single column table, which is needed to drive the aggregation.